# .htaccess Optional characters?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Though .htaccess, I want to redirect /page/var1/var2 to ./page.php?var1=var1&var2=var2. This is very easy BUT I want to make it so /page/var1 also redirects to ./page.php?var1=var1 (without having the var2). The only way I'm doing this is:

```
RewriteRule page/(.*)$ ./page.php?var1=$1
RewriteRule page/(.*)/(.*)$ ./page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

As you can see it's very redundant, and I have a ton of lines like this, so it gets very messy. Any way to define "optional" parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `.*` matches both `var1` and `var1/var2` thus the first rule is applied on both.

So you have to specify it that the first rule only matches `var1`. This can be done by replacing `.` (any character) by `[^/]` (any character except `/`). So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)$ ./page.php?var1=$1
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ./page.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
```

**Edit**   You can also write this in one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ ./page.php?var1=$1&var2=$3
```

Comment: I think mod_rewrite stops when it finds a match, so as long as I put the two vars one before the one var one, it will be fine, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite is not well suited to such heavy lifting, leave that to your PHP app.

```
 RewriteRule page/(.*)$ ./page.php?vars=$1
```

and somewhere near the beginning of page.php:

```
 <?php
 $vars = explode('/',$_GET['vars']);
```

Voila, you have an array of your vars; now you could do some processing there to see what is required/optional for your app and react accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, so basically, it is not possible to do it with .htaccess?

Comment: It is possible, but as you have already found out, it is not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to just hand everything over to your PHP script.

I wrote an article on how to do [friendly URLs](http://www.hm2k.com/posts/friendly-urls), which covers this in more detail.